# Synapse User role - able to scale SQL Pool - How to prevent this?

Tags: azure-synapse

We have a group that has been assigned the Synapse "User" Role which is a readonly role. However, they are able to scale the SQL Pool in the Synapse Studio. How do we prevent this? I thought we needed to have Synapse "Administrator" or "SQL Administrator" roles to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the azure synapse administrator has full Synapse access to SQL pools.

If you created the custom role, you can assign it to the users who should have read-only access to azure synapse without the ability to scale the SQL pool. This will give them all the same permissions as the "User" role.

For more information refer to this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCDBhtkW0eI) it has detailed information about creating custom RBAC roles in azure.